# Open files with .SLDDRW.cvd, .NFT.cvd and .xlsm in solidworks

Tags: vb.net, solidworks

I have a couple of questions about solidworks.

I want to open some files with .SLDDRW.cvd, .NFT.cvd and .xlsm. I 've used Opendoc6, it doesn't work. Can you please help me.

Any help is welcome

Thanks

Comment: going to need code and error or other information

Answer (score 0):

According the API Open6 accpts this parameters:

```
Function OpenDoc6( _
   ByVal FileName As System.String, _
   ByVal Type As System.Integer, _
   ByVal Options As System.Integer, _
   ByVal Configuration As System.String, _
   ByRef Errors As System.Integer, _
   ByRef Warnings As System.Integer _
) As ModelDoc2
```

The Types options possible (swDocumentTypes_e) are:

```
swDocASSEMBLY 2 
swDocDRAWING 3 
swDocIMPORTED_ASSEMBLY 7; Multi-CAD 
swDocIMPORTED_PART 6; Multi-CAD 
swDocLAYOUT 5 
swDocNONE 0 
swDocPART 1 
swDocSDM
```

If using swDocDrawing it doesn't work I think it is not possible with this Open6 function.

Have a look to this post from solidworks forum, https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/57616 in special David's comment:

> A ".sldprt.cvd" file is a Virtual SolidWorks Part document   There is no data in the file which will be why you cannot open it. It will
>   have been created inside Enterprise PDM as a placeholder until someone
>   had time to create the real file. If you need to add SolidWorks data
>   to this file then you can Right Click on it and select Replace. This
>   then allows you to find a SolidWorks Part to replace the virtual
>   document with.   David

Maybe it can give you some ideas.